# Redirect to external URL in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, button, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to redirect to an external `url` by clicking a button.
In my view, in a button object, I'm calling to `myFunction()` with no parameters.

In the controller, I have the following code:

```
public ActionResult myFunction()
{
    return Redirect("www.google.com.ar");
}
```

But, when click the button, I have been redirected to "http://localhost:xxxxx/myController/www.google.com.ar".

How do I solve this?

Comment: I think that this is not possible, mayve if you do that in client side could be another option

Comment: Why don't you just add <a></a> tag with specific url under the button?

Comment: I didn't do that way because I have to close my session (log off and clear credentials) in the same function. The redirect is just the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also:

```
<input type="button" id="buttonid" value="Destination" onclick="window.location.href='<%= Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName") %>';" />
```

Or

```
 return Content("<script>window.location = 'http://www.example.com';</script>");
```

Or

Use javascript to redirect:

```
$( "#buttonid" ).click(function() {

 var url =  "http://www.example.com";

     location.href = url; 

});
```